# Rich Edit control: Prevent immediate repainting/updating?

Tags: windows-controls

I'm trying to replace some text in a range in a rich edit control. The two line way to do it is by sending a `EM_EXSETSEL` followed by a `EM_REPLACESEL`. However, this causes an annoying flickering when the text is briefly selected, before being replaced. Is there any way to suspend repainting? I'm hoping for something like this:

```
SendMessage(EM_SUSPEND_PAINTING)
SendMessage(EM_EXSETSEL)
SendMessage(EM_REPLACESEL)
SendMessage(EM_RESUME_PAINTING)
```

(with the appropriate WPARAM and LPARAM values, of course)

Answer (score 1):

The [EM_HIDESELECTION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774210(v=VS.85).aspx) command is most excellent.